# How to compile FANN with C++ wrapper?

Tags: c++, wrapper, neural-network, fannj

I am trying to wrap the [FANN library](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) with attached to the download zip wrapper (`fann_cpp.h`) but I have no idea how to do it. When I compile the library normally i don't get any errors but when I

`#include "fann_cpp.h"`

in my source or the library's source then i get these  errors (100 of them) :

> Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'  c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio 39  libfann
>
> Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ':' c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio   39  libfann

**EDIT**

The errors are more or less on these lines of `cstdio`

```
using ::_Filet;

using ::size_t; using ::fpos_t; using ::FILE;
using ::clearerr; using ::fclose; using ::feof;
using ::ferror; using ::fflush; using ::fgetc;
using ::fgetpos; using ::fgets; using ::fopen;
using ::fprintf; using ::fputc; using ::fputs;
using ::fread; using ::freopen; using ::fscanf;
using ::fseek; using ::fsetpos; using ::ftell;
using ::fwrite; using ::getc; using ::getchar;
using ::gets; using ::perror;
using ::putc; using ::putchar;
```

**EDIT2**

I do not know if this might be the case but I have sorted out one thing :

- I have been working on the project attached to solution with the library itself so I think it might have been the problem because it is in C (not C++)
- I have made a new project in C++ copied all the settings etc. and now it works

Comment: Its most likely that there is probably just a syntax error in `fann_cpp.h`, such as a missing `};`. This is then propagating the error into cstdio which is your next header included.